# Data Entry layout (XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm very new to WPF and I want to create a modal popup settings manager. My clients can be using my application on different resolution. I also want to extend my settings manager later and add more fields (textbox etc). I've created a basic version of it but I'm not sure if I've followed all the best practices in designing the layout (type of panel, width/height of elements etc). I'm attaching a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve and I'm also attaching XAML with this post. I would really appreciate your feedback if there is any changes I can do to improve the layout (to make it more maintainable as I'm going to add lot more forms like this very soon).

Note: I know I've hardcoded text (no localization support etc) for now, but right now I'm just concerned about layout. I'd really appreciate your help.

```
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Width="350" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="11" Foreground="#FFFEFFFC" Text="This is the header containing information related to my dialogbox. It can be multiple lines aswell." Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Padding="5" />

    <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="My Group Box" Margin="5" Padding="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <StackPanel  Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="My Label1" />
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Crimson" Content="*" />
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" MaxLength="255" />
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Visible"  Margin="0,2,0,0" Name="labelError1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FFD80000" Text="Error Message for my textbox1" MaxWidth="455"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel  Grid.Row="2"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="My Label 2" />
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Crimson" Content="*"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" MaxLength="255" />
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Visible"  Margin="0,2,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FFD80000" Text="Error Message for my textbox2" MaxWidth="455"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
        <Button Name="OkButton" Width="88" Height="28"  IsDefault="True" Content="OK"  Command="{Binding Path=OkCommand, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Margin="0,0,6,0"/>
        <Button Name="CancelButton" Width="88" Height="28" IsCancel="True" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

```
<Window xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"  
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="My Settings Manager" 
        SizeToContent="Height"
        Background="#ffe6e6e6"
        MinWidth="350"
        MinHeight="290"
        Width="350"
        >

    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="11" Foreground="#FFFEFFFC" Text="This is the header containing information related to my dialogbox. It can be multiple lines aswell." Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Padding="5" />

        <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="My Group Box" Margin="5" Padding="5">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="My Label1" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Crimson" Text="*" Margin="4,2,0,0"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" MaxLength="255" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,2,0,0" Name="labelError1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FFD80000" Text="Error Message for my textbox1" />

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="My Label1"  />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Crimson" Text="*" Margin="4,2,0,0"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" MaxLength="255" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,2,0,0" Name="labelError2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FFD80000" Text="Error Message for my textbox1" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

    <Button Grid.Row="2" Name="OkButton" Width="88"   IsDefault="True" Content="OK" Padding="0,3,0,3" Margin="0,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Name="CancelButton" Width="88" IsCancel="True" Content="Cancel"  Margin="0,5,100,5" Padding="0,3,0,3" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things stand out to me...

- Generic names of your UI objects. I hate seeing things named `label1`, `textbox1`, etc. Either name them something descriptive, or don't specify a name at all for them. Typically I don't name anything unless I need to reference it somewhere in the code.
- You're using a `Grid` for rows, then Horizontal StackPanels for columns. Why aren't you using the `Grid` for both your Rows and your Columns? There will be less objects in your UI tree that way, and your columns will be lined up
- You don't need to set a lot of the default things. For example, controls are `Visible` by default, so `Visibility="Visible"` seems unnecessary and just makes the code harder to read
- Some of your generic stuff can be placed in a Style instead of in the `<Tag>` to make it easier to read the XAML. Typically I try and place all styling properties (`Margin`, `Height`, `Alignment`, etc) in `<Style>` tags, and only keep relevant layout properties (such as `DockPanel.Dock` or `Grid.Column`) and data (`Text`, `Tooltip`, `Command`, etc) in the body of the XAML.

Comment: Hello Rachel, thanks for your response. I thought about using Grid Columns instead of stackpanel for horizontal alighment of my controls. But as you can see that my first row has two elements (Label1 and *) and second and third row has one one element (textbox and a textblock). Show I create two columns and use span = 2 for textbox and textblock?

Comment: I've updated the code, can you please have a look and let me know if layout looks fine now? I'm going to apply style/themes and rename the elements once I'd understand this layout and panel stuff properly :)

Comment: @tkl33 Sure, that looks fine. There typically isn't any one-right-way to layout your UI. Just try and make it easy to maintain (readable code, descriptive names, etc), and try not to use unnecessary UI components. If you're new to WPF layouts, I'd highly recommend looking over this codeproject article: [WPF Layouts - A Visual Quick Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start). I still reference it regularly when I'm trying to decide how to layout a WPF UI and want a reminder of what's available.